Flink Kubernetes Operator ok K8s - how to end pods after job is finished?

Flink Kubernetes Operator is installed according to Quick Start guide: "https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-kubernetes-operator-docs-main/docs/try-flink-kubernetes-operator/quick-start/"
Job is exetucet by command "kubectl create -f job.yaml"
Basic example is as follow: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/flink-kubernetes-operator/release-1.8/examples/basic.yaml + some additioanl customization, like:

flinkConfiguration:
  execution.shutdown-on-application-finish: "true"
  parallelism.default: "1"
  taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: "1"
  web.submit.enable: "true"
  restart-strategy: failure-rate
  restart-strategy.failure-rate.max-failures-per-interval: "3"
  restart-strategy.failure-rate.failure-rate-interval: 5 min
  restart-strategy.failure-rate.delay: 15 s
job:
  jarURI: local:///opt/flink/usrlib/test.jar
  parallelism: 1
  upgradeMode: stateless  


When job is finished jobmanager continue to run but from my understanding everything should be finished and cleared. How to achieve it?

execution.shutdown-on-application-finish: "true" was added but after job is finished, I can log to the Flink Dashboard and under JobManager -> Configuration I can see that execution.shutdown-on-application-finish is set to false.
What parameter I need to add to delete deployment automatically without using "kubectl delete -f job.yaml"?

If your job is finished and you are looking to clean up the related pods for it, you can set the job state (spec.job.state) to "suspended":
spec:
  ...
  job:
    ...
    state: suspended

Finished is a terminal job state, so the job will still appear in Kubernetes. I'm not aware of specific configuration that would handle automatically deleting the FlinkDeployment once the job has finished. You might have to consider implementing a cron job that would monitor the deployments and delete them once they reach a "FINISHED" state.

Hi, thank you for your response.
I've created FlinkDeployment with job state: suspended but this state makes that resources aren't created.
kubectl get deployment' isn't showing anything. kubectl get flinkdeployment' is showing new deployment but without status:
> kubectl get flinkdeployment
NAME       JOB STATUS   LIFECYCLE STATE
testjob                


So i't seems that is not this parameter what I'm looking for.
